# In Python, difference in expected performance of reduce and any/all?

Tags: python, reduce, short-circuiting, any

I was trying to find out if the below operations in **Python 2.7.3** short circuit or not:

- reduce with a logical 'or' or an 'and'
- any/all

So I defined a function which sleeps for 500ms, prints the passed in value and returns it.

```
def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print 'x', x
    return x
```

Then I ran the below code using **any**, which essentially calls f() on each list element and compares the return value to 0. This will happen only on the first element of the list, which is 0.

```
In [1]: any([f(i)==0 for i in range(3)])
x 0
x 1
x 2
```

<s>This indicates any does *not* short-circuit as it calls f() on all the list elements.</s>
*It just indicates that the entire list is computed first.*
Next, I used **reduce** to evaluate the same.

```
In [2]: reduce(lambda x,y: x or f(y)==0, range(3), False)
x 0
```

<s>Clearly, **reduce** short-circuits.</s>
*Its only clear that the entire list is not computed once the call back function *or* short-circuits.*
Just to make sure, I also timed the following code

```
In [3]: timeit reduce(operator.or_, [True] * 10000, True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 390 us per loop
```

for **reduce** and

```
In [4]: timeit any([True] * 10000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.8 us per loop
```

for **any**. From this one will conclude that **any is faster** than reduce, because it probably short-circuits. 
So what is it?

===============

## **Answer**

W.r.t. performance, the best way forward seems might be to compute a generator from the list and then use any on it.

```
In [1]: any(f(i)==0 for i in range(3))
x 0
```

Comment: `Clearly, reduce short-circuits.` - well no - its whole purpose is to produce a single value from a sequence/iterable - the only way it can do that is to consume the entire lot. The only short-circuiting you have is `x or f(y)` which won't bother executing `f(y)` if x` is Truthy... The entire input is still going to be consumed by `reduce` - you're just avoiding `f(y)` for where x is 1 or 2...

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> any([f(i)==0 for i in range(3)])
> ```

This is the same as:

```
l = [f(i)==0 for i in range(3)]  # [True, False, False]
any(l)
```

You're generating the entire list and are running `f` for every element, before `any` is invoked. You would need to use a generator instead to avoid having the entire list processed:

```
any(f(i)==0 for i in range(3))
```

This now short-circuits as expected.

And as noted by @Jon: `reduce` *never* short-circuits, it's only your callback that does. The purpose of `any` is to return `True` at the first `True` that is encountered, the purpose of `reduce` is to iterate *all* elements and return a single value at the end; and that's exactly what they do. The problem is in your part of the code here.